# peewee select where not working when using a model instance rather than a model directly

Tags: python, peewee

I have an instance of a peewee Model `my_table = MyTable()` from which I want to select some model instances.

I don't understand why this works:

```
In  [0] [selection.p_name for selection in my_table.select() if selection.p_type == "Solar"] 
Out [0] ['Solar, photovoltaic',
         'Solar, photovoltaic',
         'Solar, photovoltaic',
         'Solar, photovoltaic',
         'Solar, concentrated solar power',
         'Solar, concentrated solar power']
```

but this doesn't:

```
In  [1] selections = my_table.select().where(my_table.p_type=="Solar")
In  [2] [t.p_name for t in selections]
Out [2]
```

Nothing is output. In fact, `len(selections)=0`

Am I doing something wrong?

My model definition is in one file and is as follows:

```
cafe3db = SqliteDatabase(db_fp)

class Cafe3BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = cafe3db
class ScenarioTable(Cafe3BaseModel):
    pathway_scenario_key = CharField(primary_key=True)
    pathway_type = CharField()
    pathway_name = CharField()

cafe3db.create_tables([ScenarioTable])
```

I then populate the tables. Here is a screen capture of the SQLite database as seen DB Browswer for SQLite:
[image]

I then create an instance of the table: 
    scenario_table = ScenarioTable()

Then, in a Python shell, I import the instance:

```
from x.y import scenario_table
```

I know it has all the model instances I expect (112):

```
>>> len(scenario_table.select())
112
```

And this works:

```
>>> [t.pathway_name for t in scenario_table.select() if t.pathway_type == 'Coal']
['Coal, sub-bituminous', 'Coal, bituminous', 'Coal, lignite', 'Coal, sub-bituminous', 'Coal, lignite', 'Coal, bituminous', 'Coal, bituminous', 'Coal, lignite']
```

But this doesn't:

```
>>> [t.pathway_name for t in scenario_table.select().where(scenario_table.pathway_type == 'Coal')]
[]
```

After trial and error, I was able to make things work by importing the model directly rather than an instance of the model. 
So, rather than:

```
    from x.y import scenario_table
```

I now have:

```
    from x.y import ScenarioTable
```

and now:

```
selections = ScenarioTable.select().where(ScenarioTable.pathway_type=='Coal')
[t.pathway_name for t in selections]
```

Does return the expected list of model instance names.

So my question is now: why does the model instance `select` work, but not the model instance `where`?

Comment: If you could share your model definition (at the least the relevant fields) along with the actual schema as it exists in the database, that would be a great help.

Comment: @coleifer I've included the model definition and some screenshots of the database schema as seen in DB Browser for SQLite.

Comment: Thanks @MPa -- damn dude, looks like everything is right. I am baffled as to why that filter isn't working correctly!

Comment: Might help debug: print(scenario_table.select(scenario_table.path_type).tuples()[:])

Comment: @coleifer so I've gotten it to work by importing the actual Model (`ScenarioTable`) rather than an instance of the Model (`scenario_table`).

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to reproduce your problem, but I can't.

First I create the database and the table:

```
import peewee
db = peewee.SqliteDatabase('test.db')
db.connect()

class my_table(peewee.Model):
    p_name = peewee.CharField()
    p_type = peewee.CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = db
db.create_tables([my_table])
```

Then I insert two rows:

```
d1 = my_table(p_name="Solar, photovoltaic", p_type="Solar")
d1.save()
d2 = my_table(p_name="Windmill", p_type="Wind")
d2.save()
```

After that I try your command:

```
>>> [t.p_name for t in my_table.select().where(my_table.p_type=="Solar")]
['Solar, photovoltaic']
```

So it works here - maybe you're doing something else wrong, but the code you provided is correct

Comment: Yeah something is wrong in the user's setup. Your example shows it working as expected.

Comment: @nosklo thanks that's what I thought, and yet the problem remains... I added above the actual code snippet from my program and the output from Python...

Comment: The error must be somewhere else - maybe in the table definition?