# Why does the model instance select work, but not the model instance where?

Tags: python, peewee

This is an example database.

```
cafe3db = SqliteDatabase(db_fp)

class Cafe3BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = cafe3db
class ScenarioTable(Cafe3BaseModel):
    pathway_scenario_key = CharField(primary_key=True)
    pathway_type = CharField()
    pathway_name = CharField()

cafe3db.create_tables([ScenarioTable])
```

Here I import both the Model ScenarioTable and a Model Instance scenario_table

```
from x.y import scenario_table, ScenarioTable
```

Using the imports I run a select query with the Model and Model Instance (They are the same query and expect the same result)

```
>>> [t.pathway_name for t in scenario_table.select().where(scenario_table.pathway_type == 'Coal')]
[]

>>> [t.pathway_name for t in ScenarioTable.select().where(ScenarioTable.pathway_type=='Coal')]
['Coal' , 'Coal']
```

I cannot tell why this doesn't work. I have tried with other classes as well. Nothing seems to work with a model instance and where.

Answer (score 0):

See a pretty similar question at [peewee select where not working when using a model instance rather than a model directly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51049195/2946413).

I would like to think that you are assigning an empty model instance of `ScenarioTable` to `scenario_table`, instead of the class reference itself i.e. `scenario_table = ScenarioTable()`. This way what you are actually doing is to build up a model instance programmatically to then just save it instead of initially using it for querying the DB. See http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#creating-a-new-record.

So, if you want to actually use `scenario_table` with the same behavior as `ScenarioTable`, then what you need to do is `scenario_table = ScenarioTable`.

I tested this with a sample I created from your code:

- On one file I have:

```py
from peewee import *

cafe3db = SqliteDatabase('db')

class Cafe3BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = cafe3db

class ScenarioTable(Cafe3BaseModel):
    pathway_scenario_key = CharField(primary_key=True)
    pathway_type = CharField()
    pathway_name = CharField()

cafe3db.create_tables([ScenarioTable])
# ScenarioTable.create(pathway_scenario_key='123456', pathway_type='Coal', pathway_name='C')
```

- While in the other one I added the following:

```py
from dates import scenario_table, ScenarioTable

print([t.pathway_name for t in scenario_table.select().where(scenario_table.pathway_type == 'Coal')])
print([t.pathway_name for t in ScenarioTable.select().where(ScenarioTable.pathway_type=='Coal')])
```

- And the result I get is:

```
['C']
['C']
```

Comment: I do believe that is the case when using a model instance. The reason I was doing this was so that I could have a generalized query function where I could just pass the model Instance and this would allow to query the table according to the model instance.
Do you think that instead of passing the model instance in the function passing the Model reference its self would be a better idea?

Comment: @ShivamPatel, yes I would recommend you to only use the model instance when you want to persist any data, and use the class reference or the class itself for querying. And maybe is not the complexity that you need, but what you mention sounds to me like the repository pattern. See https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/architecture-patterns-with/9781492052197/ch02.html and https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html

Comment: The class is to be used for querying. Do not use model instances for this.